# Deploy OneNote Add-in for organization

Tags: office365, office-addins, onenote, onenote-api

I've built OneNote add-in and it works well from my local.
But there is an error when I try to upload manifest xml file to my organisation from Office admin. It doesn't give any reasons.

It seems the upload dialog saying they only support Word, Excel and PowerPoint. If that's true, how can I deploy OneNote add-in?

Answer (score 0):

OneNote currently doesn't support uploading a manifest to SharePoint.